# Почему при изменении width и height группы View элементов в RelatedLayout все эти View забывают свои местоположения?

Tags: android, xml, view, height, width

https://youtu.be/3p3x4TCwh14 (это скрин видео результата до и после изменении размеров View программным путем)

Вот ниже код с помощью которого я веду изменение width и height View элементов:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    //получаем размер экрана устройства/дисплея
    metrics = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();
    displayWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
    displayHeight = metrics.heightPixels;

    widthMultiplier =  (double) displayWidth / (double) testedWidth;
    heightMultiplier = displayHeight/(double) testedHeight;

    Log.i("userTest2020",String.valueOf("display width = " + displayWidth+"\n"+"display height = "+displayHeight));

    if(hasFocus) {
        for (TextView textView:textViews) {
            viewWidth = textView.getWidth();
            viewHeight = textView.getHeight();

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    (int)(viewWidth*widthMultiplier),
                    (int)(viewHeight*heightMultiplier));

            // Setting the parameters on the TextView
            textView.setLayoutParams(lp);
            //break;
        }

        for (ImageView imageView: imageViews) {
            viewWidth = imageView.getWidth();
            viewHeight = imageView.getHeight();

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    (int)(viewWidth*widthMultiplier),
                    (int)(viewHeight*heightMultiplier));

            // Setting the parameters on the ImageView
            imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
            //break;
        }

        /**/viewWidth = tv10.getWidth();
        viewHeight = tv10.getHeight();

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                (int)(viewWidth*widthMultiplier),
                (int)(viewHeight*heightMultiplier));

        // Setting the parameters on the ImageView
        tv10.setLayoutParams(lp);

        viewWidth = tv11.getWidth();
        viewHeight = tv11.getHeight();

        lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                (int)(viewWidth*widthMultiplier),
                (int)(viewHeight*heightMultiplier));

        // Setting the parameters on the ImageView
        tv11.setLayoutParams(lp);

        viewWidth = b1.getWidth();
        viewHeight = b1.getHeight();

        lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                (int)(viewWidth*widthMultiplier),
                (int)(viewHeight*heightMultiplier));

        // Setting the parameters on the ImageView
        b1.setLayoutParams(lp);

        viewWidth = b2.getWidth();
        viewHeight = b2.getHeight();

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                (int)(viewWidth*widthMultiplier),
                (int)(viewHeight*heightMultiplier));

        // Setting the parameters on the ImageView
        b2.setLayoutParams(lp2);

        viewWidth = b3.getWidth();
        viewHeight = b3.getHeight();

        lp2 = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                (int)(viewWidth*widthMultiplier),
                (int)(viewHeight*heightMultiplier));

        // Setting the parameters on the ImageView
        b3.setLayoutParams(lp2);/**/
    }
}
```

Есть предположение, что это связано с тем, что делать новую прорисовку - означает создать новый UI и все, что указано в xml теряет свою актуальность и все надо создавать с нуля через код. Но тогда, не нарушается ли логика, учитывая что программа все равно распознает каждый View через соответствующие id, которые были заданы в xml?

содержание соответствующего xml файла

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/pokemon_background"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/search_icon_for_searchboard_cell"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/click_me"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:visibility="visible"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv1"
            android:background="@drawable/search_icon_for_searchboard_cell"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/click_me"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv2"
            android:background="@drawable/search_icon_for_searchboard_cell"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/click_me"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv4"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv1"
            android:background="@drawable/search_icon_for_searchboard_cell"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/click_me"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv5"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv2"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv4"
            android:background="@drawable/search_icon_for_searchboard_cell"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/click_me"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv6"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv3"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv5"
            android:background="@drawable/search_icon_for_searchboard_cell"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/click_me"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv7"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv4"
            android:background="@drawable/search_icon_for_searchboard_cell"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/click_me"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv8"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv5"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv7"
            android:background="@drawable/search_icon_for_searchboard_cell"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/click_me"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv9"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv6"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv8"
            android:background="@drawable/search_icon_for_searchboard_cell"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/click_me"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/iv4"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/iv5"
            android:alpha="0.4"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/iv5"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/iv4"
            android:alpha="0.4"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/iv5"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/iv5"
            android:alpha="0.4"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv4"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/iv5"
            android:alpha="0.4"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv5"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:alpha="1"
            android:background="@drawable/pika_pika"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv6"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/iv3"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/iv5"
            android:alpha="0.4"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv7"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/iv4"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/iv5"
            android:alpha="0.4"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv8"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/iv5"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/iv6"
            android:alpha="0.4"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv9"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/iv6"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/iv5"
            android:alpha="0.4"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:alpha="0.3"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text=" "
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv10"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text=" "
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:visibility="visible" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="get resolution info"
            android:visibility="visible" />


        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b2"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="new round"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:alpha="0.3"
                android:background="@color/colorGreen"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="new round"
                android:visibility="visible" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/relative_layout"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:alpha="0.3"
                android:background="@color/colorRed"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Try the bigger board"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Try the bigger board"
                android:textColor="@color/colorYellow"
                android:visibility="visible" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:alpha="0.3"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="get resolution info"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:alpha="0.3"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv11"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="You're score is 0"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:visibility="visible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` может включать в себя взаимосвязь элементов (их зависимость друг от друга). Попробуйте не создавать новый `lp`, а получать его как копию старого. Ну и приложите изначальную верстку, пожалуйста)

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov вопрос обновил. А насчет вашего совета, думаю я уловил вашу мысль. Счас попробую.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я писал в комментариях, Вам необходимо избежать потери привязок элементов друг к другу. Можно, например, заменить создание новых `LayoutParams`

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                (int)(viewWidth*widthMultiplier),
                (int)(viewHeight*heightMultiplier));
```

на копирование

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = copyLp(textView.getLayoutParams());
```

Где метод `copyLp`:

```
private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams copyLp(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams source){
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams copy = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)source);
    return copy;
}
```

Ну и во всех подобных места по аналогии.